# Resharper weird characters/symbols

Tags: c#, resharper

I'm trying to familiarise myself with [ReSharper (R#)](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) and it seems to be working properly for the most part but I have one problem.

In areas where it wants to remove redundant data such as unused directives, it displays the redundant data as weird symbols. I think this may be a font error with my computer?

[image]

Turning off code analysis removes the problem so it has something to do with when ReSharper attempts to underline the problems.

Any ideas on how I can fix this issue?

Comment: Wow, never seen this. Ever. You mean if you turn off code analyis all those `?` diamonds go away? I think your question might be better off asked directly on JetBrains' support forums...

Comment: This looks like a problem with a display driver or something. Does it look this way _before_ you use the "Remove unused directives"? What version are you using, of R# and of Visual Studio?

Comment: Seems, problem in file encoding... Can you try to save file in another encoding before applying refactoring?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Visual Studio 2005 - you need to install Service Pack 1 according to [this article](http://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23854061-Code-turns-into-Unicode-question-marks-with-ReSharper-in-Visual-Studio-2005)